# Initializing nested  complex types using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-2.0

Code tree is like:

```
Class Data
{
    List<Primitive> obj;
}

Class A: Primitive
{
    ComplexType CTA;
}

Class B: A
{
    ComplexType CTB;
    Z o;
}

Class Z
{
   ComplexType CTZ;
}

Class ComplexType { .... }
```

Now in `List<Primitive> obj`, there are many classes in which `ComplexType` object is 'null'. I just want to initialize this to some value.

The problem is how to traverse the complete tree using reflection.

**Edit:**

```
Data data = GetData(); //All members of type ComplexType are null. 
ComplexType complexType = GetComplexType();
```

I need to initialize all 'ComplexType' members in 'data' to 'complexType'

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to achieve? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly perhaps something like this would do the trick:

```
static void AssignAllComplexTypeMembers(object instance, ComplexType value)
{
     // If instance itself is null it has no members to which we can assign a value
     if (instance != null)
     {
        // Get all fields that are non-static in the instance provided...
        FieldInfo[] fields = instance.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
           if (field.FieldType == typeof(ComplexType))
           {
              // If field is of type ComplexType we assign the provided value to it.
              field.SetValue(instance, value);
           }
           else if (field.FieldType.IsClass)
           {
              // Otherwise, if the type of the field is a class recursively do this assignment 
              // on the instance contained in that field. (If null this method will perform no action on it)
              AssignAllComplexTypeMembers(field.GetValue(instance), value);
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

And this method would be called like:

```
foreach (var instance in data.obj)
        AssignAllComplexTypeMembers(instance, t);
```

This code only works for fields of course. If you want properties as well you would have to have the loop iterate through all properties (which can be retreived by `instance.GetType().GetProperties(...)`).

Be aware though that reflection is not particularly efficient.